# Why brute force the key instead of doing it on the pbkdf2 passphrase itself?

Tags: encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I have created a binary executable using a C++ program which take a random password which is of 32 characters as command line argument, convert that into raw bytes and pass it to a AES 256 bit encryption function to encrypt few files. But I received a review from an online form that this is bad and I should consider to use PBDFK2 to generate a key from my password and then encrypt the files using that.

What I couldn't wrap my head around is, what is the purpose of using PBKDF2 if all it does is also generate a 32 bytes random string which I have to convert to raw bytes anyways and pass it to the function. Anywhere I look on the internet, people are advising to hash the passwords with PBKDF2 and then using the key it generates to do cipher operations.

I understand that PBKDF2 generates thie kind of pseudo random keys which are complicated more than passwords created by humans. But, by the end of the day, if the attacker knows which Encryption algorithm I am using say he/she knows I am using AES-256 CBC, PBKDF2 with a particular no of iterations, the salt and IV stored along with cipher text etc. If all of these parameters are known, then what's stopping him/her from directly brute force my weak password which I pass to the hashing function?

If my PBKDF2 password itself is weak, say "apple123" and it generates a key say "HfhagG28@₹&(@(/#+₹+" something, what good does it do? The attacker could simply brute force for "apple123", and whichever key that generates use that and try see if it decrypts.

Comment: This also raises a new question, why tools like openssl allow users to pass a passphrase using -p pass: syntax. What good is using PBKDF2 under the hood if the main password itself is weak?

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/whats-the-advantage-of-using-pbkdf2-vs-sha256-to-generate-an-aes-encryption-key. To summarize: PBKDF2 is slow (intentionally), so the brute force attack is slow as well.

Comment: @Progman. Ok I understood from the link that PBKDF2 delays the key generation intentionally so you have to try so many iterations to get to the correct key to decrypt the files, but still PBKDF2 alone won't help if the user decides to go with a password such as "linkedin123" I guess. It's just a matter of time and resources. On the other hand, if I use a strong and proper random Password, I would not need something like PBKDF2 before I encrypt my files isn't it? PBKDF2 makes sense in hash validation on the web, not I don't see it's use in solo encryption tools like openssl. Am I correct?

Comment: openssl uses PBKDF2 as well for the same reason, to generate the encryption key based of a passphrase (but generate it very slowly). Keep in mind that the passphrase can be of any arbitrary length, but the encryption key for the cipher has to be of a specific length.

Comment: *But I received a review from an online form that this is bad* What does the form know? Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the other hand, if I use a strong and proper random Password, I would not need something like PBKDF2 before I encrypt my files isn't it?

Correct. If your password were 64-characters long, made up of completely random hexadecimal digits, or about 39-characters long, made up of completely random characters than be typed on a common keyboard. Most people's "strong" passwords are nowhere near these lengths, and "strong" passwords almost never are random over all reasonably-typeable characters.

The output of `PBKDF2("apple123")` is nowhere near as trivial as `HfhagG28@₹&(@(/#+₹+`. You're correct, that if it were that trivial (~23 non-random bytes), then it wouldn't be particularly useful. But it isn't. It outputs 32 bytes that are indistinguishable from random. 2<sup>256</sup> is much, much, much larger than 2<sup>184</sup>, even if the output you're describing were fully random. The fact that ₹, +, (, and @, all appear twice in less than 2 dozen characters suggests this isn't very random. And the fact that it's printable in UTF-8 at all means it's over a tiny space compared to a full AES key. The overwhelming majority of 32-byte sequences are not valid UTF-8.

Brute forcing the PBKDF2 space is incredibly more expensive than brute forcing the underlying space. By orders of magnitude. Against strong passwords, you're better off brute forcing the key rather than the password. (Not that brute forcing the key is possible.)

But you are correct that for a very weak password, it is certainly possible to guess it in reasonable time, even with PBKDF2. PBKDF2 can't protect the weakest of passwords. But it can make reasonably strong passwords effectively as good as truly random passwords, and that's the point.

Comment: Awesome answer. Also thanks for confirming my understanding. It's also interesting to think of the utf-8 printable chars in my password vs the invalid utf-8 32 byte keys PBKDF2 generates.I can also relate to the very last point you said but not the exact words, "PBKDF2 takes a reasonable strong password and makes it kinda truly random".

Comment: The output of PBKDF2 is believed to be "indistinguishable from random." This has a precise, technical definition (explore [pseudorandom functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) for details if you're curious), but it basically means what it sounds like. There is no practical way to tell the difference between the output of PBKDF2 and a totally random key over the entire keyspace. "Practical" and "tell the difference" gloss over some important technical details of the definition, but that's the sense of it.

Comment: An extremely important detail is that PBKDF2 is tunable such that it can be made arbitrarily difficult on the attacker at a small incremental cost to the defender. By setting the iteration count, I can make computing each hash take as long as I like, at the cost of a single hashing operation to me. But the attacker must perform it for every test. Even a quite simple password can take tens of thousands of guesses to find. Something of even moderate complexity can take trillions of guesses. This can easily make brute-forcing the password impractical using even a 100ms delay.

Comment: BTW, if you have further questions on cryptography, I highly recommend crypto.stackexchange.com. SO is really for programming-specific questions. Questions about cryptographic theory belong on crypto.se.